# how to define '.$file.' as key POST array

Tags: php, get

i had a problem with my php script.
im using php to show all my picture in folder "gambar"  and then i want to add button command in every picture i've showed to other folder i already make.
im using POST syntax and had trouble with it. button show up but not executing command to moving file i've choose. 
this is script i've use, could somebody help me with this?

```
    <?php

    $folder = "gambar"; //folder tempat gambar disimpan
    $handle = opendir($folder);
    echo '<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10" width="90%" >';
    echo '<tr>';
    $i = 1;
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
    echo '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;" align="center" >

      <div class="hvrbox">
      <img src="gambar/'.$file.'" alt="Mountains" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom" 
      width="100%" />
      <div class="hvrbox-layer_top">
      <div class="hvrbox-text"> '.$file.'.</div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hover-box.js"></script>    
            </select>
            <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" select name="datae" value="'.$file.'" /> 

            >>> <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
            --- 
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" /><<<
            </form>
            <br /><b>NAMA FILE:</b>   '.$file.'</td>';

      if(($i % 1) == 0){
      echo '</tr><tr>';
      }
      $i++;
      }
      }
      echo '</tr>';
      echo '</table>';
      ?>
```

and to progress POST im using this script

```
            <?php
            // Turn off all error reporting
            error_reporting(0);

            if (isset($_POST['upload']) && isset($_POST['datae'])) {
            rename('gambar/'.$_POST['datae'], 'Upload/'.$_POST['datae']);
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>";
            }

            if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['datae'])) {
            rename('gambar/'.$_POST['datae'], 'delete/'.$_POST['datae']);
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>";
            }
            ?>
```

cz when i use

```
      <form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" select name="datae" value="'.$file.'" />
```

so did

```
     ($_POST['datae']
```

still not moving the files to other folder, its like the script was working but no files moved to destination folder.

PS. im sorry cz my English is BAD. but i wish you could understand what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the `<form>`.  So when you click your "submit" button there's nothing to submit.  Wrap a form element around your buttons and include an input for the file name:

```
echo '
    ...
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="file" value="'.$file.'" />
        >>> <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
        --- 
        --- <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" /><<<
    </form>
    ...';
```

Also in your server-side code you are incorrectly getting a value from the POST array:

```
$_POST['.$file.']
```

The syntax is broken, and it appears that you're trying to use the file name itself as the key in the POST array.  Posted data is in key/value pairs.  You want to use the *name* of the value in order to get the value.  Notice the `name` attribute in my hidden input above.  That's what you'd use:

```
$_POST['file']
```

---

A few important things to note which are outside the scope of the question being asked but definitely relevant:

1. If your server-side code is on a different page then you'll need to specify that in the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element and handle going back and forth between the pages.
2. If your server-side code is on the same page but the data is modified *after* the output is rendered then you won't see updates until you reload the page again.  Perform the requested actions before building the output.
3. **WARNING:** You are allowing users to *specify the file name* that they want to modify on your server.  *Users can abuse this access.*  You're going to want to add some security to make sure that user is permitted to modify that file.  As it stands there's nothing stopping a user from manually specifying important system files and your code will blindly move/delete/etc. those files, which can corrupt your server.  In general it's best to store records of your files in a database and use an identifier from the database for user interaction, so the user never knows or has any interaction with the file system but rather just specifies IDs.  This also allows you to control permissions by associating certain files with certain users, etc.

Comment: already try like you said but still  not execute the image to move to destination folder

Comment: @gregoriusaryanto: If you have updated your code then please update the question to include that code, as well as information about specifically in what way that code doesn't do what you expect.  Such as the runtime values and behaviors of your code when you debug.

Comment: @gregoriusaryanto: In your updated code you are using *both* `file` and `datae` server-side: `rename('gambar/'.$_POST['file'], 'delete/'.$_POST['datae']);`  But you only send `datae` from your form.  It looks like you just forgot to update your server-side code to fully match the form.  You're sending `datae`, so use `datae`.

Comment: after read this i'd changing $_POST['file'] to $_POST['datae']. and the result still the same.

Comment: @gregoriusaryanto: Then now it's time to do some debugging.  Add various forms of output to your PHP code to better observe what it's doing.  Are you entering the `if` blocks at all?  What are the runtime values being used in the `rename` command?  Do they fully match the intended file paths?  Are there any errors or warnings at all in the PHP logs?  You're going to need to get more specific than "it's not working".